# Several sites in www dir. .htaccess problems

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several Phalcon apps in www dir.

This structure looks like this:

```
www/
  /app1
      .htaccess
      /public
          .htaccess
          index.php
      /app
  /app2
      .htaccess
      /public
          .htaccess
          index.php
      /app
```

.htaccess in app root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/     [L]
    RewriteRule  (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess in public dirs

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I got them from Phalcon docs.
I will get the right page if I type any relevant url like example.com/app1/page.
But I have a problem with home page.
Browser redirects to example.com/app1/public.

I need help with htaccess, I've spend 3 hours searching for solution with no success.

I can't use virtual host to resolve this problem.

Comment: _“But I have a problem with home page”_ – what do you mean by that? What URL specifically are you requesting? And what do you mean by _“.htaccess in app root”_ – a .htaccess in `/www`, or in each of `/www/app1`, `/www/app2`?

Comment: @CBroe I get my home page but server requests me example.com/app1/public. “.htaccess in app root” means that it located in each /www/app1/ and /www/app2/

Comment: @CBroe I haven't any .htaccess in /www/ dir.

Comment: Again: What do you mean by “But I have a problem with home page”, _what is the URL you are requesting in your browser?_

Comment: Well, in that case `RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]` does exactly what you asked it to do … it redirects  the request for an “empty” path to `public/`.

Comment: Are you going to `http://example.com/app1` or  `http://example.com/app1/` (note trailing slash)?

Comment: @CBroe This solution doesn't work. It still redirect to `http://example.com/app1/public` when I request `example.com/app1`. All my other links like `example.com/app1/page` don't work after this changes in htaccess. Apache is giving me 404.

Comment: @JonLin Both of them. But in the future I want to trim last slash.

Comment: Well, `(.*)` in your second rule still matches an empty path. But why would you _not_ want those requests to be rewritten to `/public` anyway? In general the _purpose_ of such a `public` folder is to have everything that is accessible from the web reside in there and _only_ in there – so your wish to be able to reach something else when only requesting `/app1/` makes little sense IMHO.

Comment: (However there is nothing in the code you have shown that would indicate an _external_ redirect – so if you still see an external redirect happen, then I doubt if you have shown us _everything_ …?)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible this is being caused by mod_dir. By default, mod_dir will redirect every request for a directory that's missing the trailing slash to the URL that includes the trailing slash. Since mod_dir and mod_rewrite both get applied to the same request, the weird redirection is happening. Something like this:

1. Request is made for `/app1`
2. mod_dir sees the request is for a directory, flags the request to be redirected to `/app1/`.
3. The request (which is now `/app1/`) continues through the processing pipeline
4. mod_rewrite sees the request and applies the rewrite rule, the request is now `/app1/public/`
5. At the end of the pipeline, the request is redirected because it was flagged by mod_dir
6. `/app1/public/` appears in the browser's URL location bar

To circumvent this, you need to turn off mod_dir's `DirectorySlash` directive. There's something **really** important that this redirect does, though. The reason is because it's possible to list the contents of a directory when you request it without a trailing slash even if there's an index file. So to safeguard from that, you need to make sure to turn off indexes.

So in the htaccess file in your document root, you want something like:

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it is great. But it still don't work :( `/public/` still appears in the browser when I request a home page with `http://example.com/app1/`. Doesn't matter with a trailing slash or not. Surprisingly, browser shows me the content of a home page so request walk into php. With other pages like `http://example.com/app1/page` everything is ok, `/public/` doesn't appear and php works.